# Remove a column from query result (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following SQL query:

### **Query**

```
WITH selectRow AS
(
    SELECT *, row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    ) FROM myTable
 )
 SELECT * FROM selectRow 
 WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

With this query I retrieve 10 data rows of all my columns from my table **AND** an extra column with the row numbers. However I don't want this row number column, I only want the actual columns from the table itself. I did a search on the internet but couldn't find anything useful. I tried some things myself but they didn't gave me the result I was expecting.

Comment: just put the name of the columns you want instead the `*`

Comment: List the fields you want in the second select instead of *

Comment: Only mention the fields of myTable

Comment: The problem is that those names are different every time (query is excuted from my c# application). I could get the column names first with a seperate query and then put the column names string inside this query. However that would take up two seperate queries. I was wondering if I could combine those two to one query. Already tried to use another select statement (SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE myTable) at the position of the '*'. However it is not allowed to put a select statement inside a select statement, atleast not via the way i did it.

Comment: @WonderTiger: Why don't you put these information in question it self in the first place?? No one knows what  you trying to do!!!

Comment: Perhaps it will be simpler to consider throwing away the column on the client side? Compared to the rest of the table, it's probably not much data and since SQL is not very good at this kind of flexibility, most other solutions tend to require additional processing or cause another query anyway.

Comment: On another note: How can your C# app know the table name but not the column names? You could build a mapping table "Tablename to Columnlist" from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS just once (at startup or lazy at first use) and use that for all these queries? Do you really need ALL columns? Or would it not be better to DECIDE in your app what the relevant columns are anyway?

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH selectRow AS
(
    SELECT *, row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    ) FROM myTable
 )
 SELECT Column_names FROM selectRow 
 WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Note:Use column_names=column names what ever u required.

Answer (score 1):

I see the ROW_NUMBER() function is unnecessary here, because you are using over (select 1), which means nothing. 
Instead you can use the below simply using "TOP n"

```
select top 10 * from myTable
```

If you need range:

Then the way I see is to use NOT IN:

```
select top 10 * from myTable 
where id not in (select top 20 id from mytable)
```

If you have sql server 2012 you can use "offset"

```
     select * from myTable
     order by id
     offset 10 rows
     fetch next 20 rows only
```

Comment: I guess that's too specific. He said he wants to retrieve "10 datarows", which probably means he wants to get rows 11 to 20 for the next page. That won't work with "TOP 10"

Comment: What Oliver said is right. It will change on the selection from the user.

Comment: What SQL Server version you are using?

Comment: We run mostly version 2005 and 2008.

Comment: Then the way I see is to use NOT IN: 
select top 10 * from myTable 
where id not in (select top 10 id from mytable)

If you have sql server 2012 you can use "offset"

Comment: @masum7: Wow...this is actually extremely clever! I did a few tests and this is acutally faster than the rownumber approach for about the first ten pages. It gets slower for large offsets but usually these are rare cases.